# What does it mean that an upload is synchronous but a download asynchronous from the server's perspective?

Tags: asynchronous, tcp, architecture, server, connection

I'm reading one of those [articles on system design](https://www.educative.io/collection/page/5668639101419520/5649050225344512/5673385510043648) (requires registration). There is one point I fail to understand:

> Since most of the web servers have connection limit, we should keep
>   this thing in mind before designing our system. Synchronous connection
>   for uploads, but downloads can be asynchronous. Let’s assume if a web
>   server can have maximum 500 connections at any time, and it can’t have
>   more than 500 concurrent uploads simultaneously. **Since reads can be
>   asynchronous, the web server can serve a lot more than 500 users at
>   any time, as it can switch between users quickly**. This guides us to
>   have separate dedicated servers for reads and writes so that uploads
>   don’t hog the system.

From my understanding, "downloads can be asynchronous" means that the client (browser) can request the image in a separate thread from the one that renders the page, but still, the server would need one connection to send the image. How comes it can "switch between users quickly"?

The server needs a TCP connection alive for the download as much as it needs it for the upload, isn't that right? I'm quite confused about this. Could somebody please elaborate?

Comment: It's nonsense. Web servers can have many many thousands of connections at a time, but they can't have more concurrently active users than connections, and the idea of separate servers for reads and writes is drivel. Uploads don't hog the system any more than downloads. Don't rely on arbitrary Internet junk.